# chrome.contextmenus how to get html instead of string

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm new on chrome extension, 
I'm creating a basic extension, thats will show the selected html with tags (`spans`, `divs` and all other `DOMs`) on an `alert`

I try this `chrome.contextMenus.create` (code below) but it showing just the selected string

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Selected HTML", contexts:["selection"], onclick: showSelectedHtml});
```

I just want to know if theres a way to get selected html doms(with tags if available) instead of string!

Thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) contextMenus API can't do that.

The solution is to run a content script that gets the HTML and returns it into your background script.

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": ["activeTab", "contextMenus"],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
```

background.js:

```
// in Chrome the menus should be created only at install/update
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'sel',
    title: 'Selected HTML',
    contexts: ['selection'],
  }, () => chrome.runtime.lastError); // ignore errors about an existing id
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    code: `(${getSelectedHtml})()`,
    frameId: info.frameId,
    matchAboutBlank: true,
    runAt: 'document_start',
  }, data => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      alert('Error: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
      prompt('HTML', data[0]);
    }
  });
});
// this function's code will be executed as a content script in the web page
function getSelectedHtml() {
  const sel = getSelection();
  let html;
  if (sel.rangeCount) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneContents());
    html = div.innerHTML;
  }
  return html || '';
}
```

Note: don't use the `onclick` property in contextMenus.create() because it doesn't work with `"persistent":false` background script, which is the preferred type ([more info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)).